# TFS: system.state rules and conditions

Tags: tfs, customization, workitem

I need help in TFS work item customization please.

Here is the scenario:

I have fields called “Priority” (Ref Name: ‘ABC.VSTS.Common.Priorities’) and “State” (Ref name: ‘System.State’)

Priority has drop down list of (ALLOWEDVALUES):

- High,
- Medium,
- Low,
- Minor,
- Urgent,
- Emergency.

State transitions are as follows:

- Closed,
- Approved,
- Rejected,
- Completed,
- In Progress,
- Cancelled,
- Submitted.
- Pending mgr Approval.

What I’m looking is, When user picks ‘Urgent’, I want to see state filed values ‘Submitted’, ‘Approved’, and ‘Rejected’. I don’t want to see other remaining status values.

Similarly When I pick Minor, I want to see only ‘Submitted’ and ‘Completed’. I tried several ways but could not figure out. All status values are showing up always.

Comment: You can do this view custom transition rules, you have not said what transitions you have and what state(s) will the work item be in when the priority is set? Will it only be "In Progress"? Note: you can only have one initial state IIRC.

Comment: What sort of assistance are you looking for? If you are looking for code, would you (a) show us what you have, (b) show us any research you have done already e.g. the "several ways" you mentioned, and (c) indicate where you are stuck in particular.

Comment: Hi Dave,
Thanks for the response. Initial state is ‘Submitted’. Then I have Seven transitions from Submitted to Closed, Approved, Rejected, Completed, In Progress, Cancelled, Pending mgr Approval. Obviously,the dropdown of STATUS field shows all seven in it ….independent of what I select the PRIORITY (High, Urgent, Emergency etc). 
My requirement is….The PRIORITY filed should control what to display in STATUS filed. For example when user selects Urgent (PRIORITY), then user should see only Approved and Rejected in the STATUS field.
I tried with four Conditional rules,but it did not work

Comment: Hi Halfer, here is what I did:
<FieldDefinition name="State" refname="System.State" type="String" reportable="dimension">
  <WHEN field="ABC.VSTS.Common.Priorities" value="Urgent">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="Approved" />
      <LISTITEM value="Rejected" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>
  <HELPTEXT>Current Status</HELPTEXT>
</FieldDefinition>
The error I was getting:
TF26062: Rule ‘<ALLOWEDVALUES expand items=“true”><ALLOWEDVALUES>’ is not supported for the field ‘System.State’

Comment: Hi Murali, firstly when replying to people (e.g. @DaveShaw - see above) please use their `@handle` - otherwise they may not see it. I did not receive a notification from your message, and just noticed it now by chance. Secondly, please delete your two comments and copy them into your question by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35188483/edit) - as you can see, code does not render well in comments here. You can then comment to say the question has been updated. Thanks.

Comment: Still would like to see your code edited into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [conditional rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194966.aspx) in TFS?

```
<FIELD refname="MyCorp.Severity" name="Customer Severity" type="String">
    <ALLOWEDVALUES>
        <LISTITEM value="Blocking" />
        <LISTITEM value="Major" />
        <LISTITEM value="Minor" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
    <WHEN field="MyCorp.CustomerReported" value="true">
        <REQUIRED />
    </WHEN>
</FIELD>
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried with all four Conditional rules. it did not work.